# What is the autofocus field in Django PasswordChangeForm?

Tags: python, django, autofocus

I'm looking through the Django documentation and found this line of code I don't get, specifically the autofocus part

```
class PasswordChangeForm(SetPasswordForm):
"""
A form that lets a user change their password by entering their old
password.
"""
error_messages = {
    **SetPasswordForm.error_messages,
    'password_incorrect': _("Your old password was entered incorrectly. Please enter it again."),
}
old_password = forms.CharField(
    label=_("Old password"),
    strip=False,
    widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'autocomplete': 'current-password', 'autofocus': True}),
)

field_order = ['old_password', 'new_password1', 'new_password2']

def clean_old_password(self):
    """
    Validate that the old_password field is correct.
    """
    old_password = self.cleaned_data["old_password"]
    if not self.user.check_password(old_password):
        raise ValidationError(
            self.error_messages['password_incorrect'],
            code='password_incorrect',
        )
    return old_password
```

in the widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'autocomplete': 'current-password', 'autofocus': True}) part, I don't get what the autofocus field is and what it does when it says it's True.

What is the purpose of this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

autofocus: True makes the "old_password" input field automatically get focus when the page loads. It is as simple as that

Comment: but what does it mean to 'get focus'?

Comment: It highlights that specific input section. Here its 'old password' field